# Git link to repository folder

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I do have a question: How can I link within a git repository to a folder of another repository.

I have the following structure:

### Repository One

.git

Folder A

Folder B

### Repository Two

.git

Folder C

Folder D

So what I now want is, that within my repository One and its Folder B, Folder D of Repository Two is referenced.
It's important that I do not reference the whole repository C, but just the Folder D of it.

I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way, if your Os supports it (and even Windows does since Vista), is to use a symlink for referring to folder `D` from folder `B`.
But you would maintain the two repos separate.

git submodule wouldn't be adapted to your case, since it refers to the all repo as a module.